# How to format float decimals when using Value With Pattern binding?

Tags: binding, interface-builder, string-formatting, decimal-point

I have an NSTextField, which is bound to a float value through Interface Builder via "Value with Pattern" field. The default display pattern is **%{value1}@**

Is there any way I can modify that line to have my output formatted to 2 decimal places? Or is that only possible through code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just been trying to do this, as well.  You can drag a Number Formatter from the object library on top of the object you want to format.  One of the property pages for the formatter allows you to choose from a list of predefined formats, or choose custom and make your own.